# High battery use with firebase pod

Tags: ios, firebase

hi everyone i am working with firebase and i realized that i have a high battery consumption when i start my app .. i noticed that the battery consumption is high even when i use empty projects but with firebase inside .. there I show a screen shot of one of my projects(empty) .. am I doing something wrong or does firebase have any of these problems?

[image]

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

I try to be as clear as possible in my question ....

Then I create a new xCode Project as Single View Application ..

This is my "Empty Project"

[image]

---

Now this is the state of Energy Impact without having installed the Firebase pod

[image]
[image]

---

Now I open the Terminal and after creating the podFile, I load the Firebase pods

[image]

---

After following the Firebase start guide and copying the GoogleService-Info.plist file into my xCode project I insert `FirebaseApp.configure()` in the `AppDelegate.swift` file

[image]

---

Now I start my new application and as you can see the **Energy Impact** is high and remains a little bit before going back to a low level ..

[image]

---

I wanted to know if it's normal to have these energy impacts using firebase or if I'm doing something wrong

Are there any problems that could arise during app development having these initial values? I don't want to accuse but I just want to understand :)

Comment: I don't like one word answers but... are you doing something wrong? yes. Firebase doesn't have that level of consumption on a regular basis and never when idling. Unfortunately there's not enough info in the question to help further. We don't know what the code is, which firebase product you're using or any other important details. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you can provide some code examples we can take a look. Also, what does an 'empty project but with Firebase' look like?

Comment: @Jay thanks for your answer i just updated my question .. i hope i was clear in my explanation

Comment: Yes, much better and more clear. Can you try doing all the same steps but remove the Analytics from your podfile? You say when you run the app the Energy Impact goes up and then returns to a lower level. I would expect that as when the app starts, it talks to the server so they can get on the same page and continues to talk to the server until data is synched (if any) and analytics are completed. So that sounds normal. Also, in general, please include any code or structure data as text (like your podfile) so we can use them in an answer if needed.

Comment: @Jay
I have just removed the analistics but I still have an overhead at 29% it goes down very slowly .. the energy impact seems to be always high...so you think it's normal and that this doesn't affect the app

Comment: Yeah - that doesn't look abnormal. Which real device are you testing this on?

Comment: @Jay yes iPhone X Pro Max

Comment: Same here, have you resolved it?