# iOS : Are Firebase and Google AdMob consuming too much energy? Can I improve this?

Tags: ios, energy

I have created a simple application that does absolutely nothing, just to compare its energy usage to the same app but embedding `Firebase` and `GoogleAdMob`.

Here is the energy impact of this app without dependencies:

[image]

Now here is the same check, embedding `Firebase` and `GoogleAdMob`:

**Podfile**

```
use_frameworks!

target 'Test' do
    platform :ios, '10.0'
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end
```

**AppDelegate**

Added in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
```

Result :

[image]

So I want to know, should I mind this? If so, is there something I can do to improve the situation?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

High-energy consumption with pods like these is normal on start-up. It should drop with time. Also consider if you really need all of these pods.

Someone else also reported this issue a while ago: [High battery use with firebase pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61762691/high-battery-use-with-firebase-pod)

Please also refer to this: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3242#issuecomment-505331258